# SSPI Negotiate not found

Tags: c++, security, package, sspi

I'm using Windows XP Pro SP3.
I want to use SSPI functions in my code.
I compiled my code, no error.

I set the security package to be used to **Negotiate**, which is recommended.

When I start my program, **Negotiate** cannot be used because it can't be found.
So, I tried "Kerberos" instead, and same error: the security package cannot be found.

I had a look at the registry, and according to that key: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Lsa/Security Packages**, the security packages available are: **kerberos**, **msv1_0**, **schannel**, **wdigest**. **Negotiate** and **NTLM** are missing.

I don't understand why my program can't find any security package.
The returned error code is **0x80090305** and I couldn't find any hint about a way to fix it.

So, if you master the SSPI, please I need your help!
Do I have something to modify in the registry?
Or maybe I need to register some DLLs?

Thanks for any hint
Bye!

Comment: It's been a *very* long time since I looked at SSPI, but don't trust the documentation; it's wrong. I seem to remember there are two ways to do this which are *meant* to be equivalent but aren't (only one returns the full list of security packages). I'll see if I can dig out the code, but no promises.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is wrong... I had to fix many errors! ... and finally it compiles, but cannot find the security packages :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSPI is a cow to debug without code :)

Try this code, see if it works, if it does, re-try it and replace NTLM with Negotiate. Actually, rather than using the word, "Negotiate" #include "security.h" and use NEGOSSP_NAME.

Also, try this, and see if Negotiate is in the list:

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ULONG cPackages = 0;
    PSecPkgInfo pInfo = NULL;
    SECURITY_STATUS stat = EnumerateSecurityPackages(&cPackages, &pInfo);
    if (stat == SEC_E_OK) {
        for (ULONG i = 0; i < cPackages; i++) {
            wprintf(L"%s\t%s\n",pInfo[i].Name, pInfo[i].Comment);
        }
        FreeContextBuffer(pInfo);
    }
    return 0;
}

make sure you define SECURITY_WIN32 in your header, and link with secur32.

Comment: one other thought - you know SSPI works in Unicode, right?? Always Unicode! Never ASCII :)

If you passed in an ASCII string to an SSPI function, it would look like Unicode goo! So make sure that if you *DO* use a string constant, prepend an 'L' to the string:

Don't use: char *szName = "Negotiate";

Use: wchar_t *wszName = L"Negotiate";

lemme know :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

The result is: Negotiate is in the list, as well as Keberos, NTLM, Schannel, WDigest, ...

Now I've got to adapt my code to unicode and see if it works :)

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, now my server works like a charm! :)